# The modification of Instruction set

Tags: microprocessor, x86

Recently I came to know that x86 instruction set can be regarded as obsolete. It should have been out of order a decade ago. Instead of being helpful, it can be called as burden. The only advantage of being backward compatible, it is slowing down the development of microprocessor. I believe it is the price you have to pay for another advantage. **So, what are the problems that makes it a burden? If so, what are the alternatives available for future computing?**

Another thing I heard is that, the current instruction sets(x86, ARM) are not really feasible for this age. They are not good enough for web related apps, GPS and more importantly cloud computing?

We are using internet, cloud computing and everything, but **why would say that it is not good enough?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try three decades ago, and you're almost there.

Comment: This question should be moved into "computer science", "programming" or "stack overflow".  The nutshell of it is that most programming is not done in assembly language any longer and x86 is hostile to compilers. It has a small number of registers, and instructions that only work with certain registers, and such. It is also hostile to efficient hardware implementation in just about any parameter of your choice: die size, power consumption, etc.  Making x86 run fast essentially requires dynamically translating the cumbersome instructions to another language which is then run by the silicon.

Comment: The statement that the CPU instruction set has any importance whatsoever on the applications you mention (web, gps, cloud) shows that this is a *very* naive question indeed. Nothing wrong with that per se, but this question is very offtopic.

Comment: not quite electrical engineering related question.  interesting concept but try seperating it and focus the question one point.  Perhaps the inefficencies of x86 assembler or c compiler compatability.  Most OS are still written in c at the lowest level.  .net /java and others are intermediary languages.  These are what web apps run on and not directly related to the assembler instruction set of the cpu

Answer (score 4):

The burden of x86 comes with the advantage of being able to run existing software.

Your statement that x86 and ARM aren't feasible is incorrect. Since they run the bulk of the computers and mobile devices, it is clear they work.

Answer (score 2):

Search and read about the design of the Pentium Pro. At a time when many people held that view about the x86 instruction set, the PPro came out. The x86 instruction set didn't stop it being the fastest CPU of its day.